# Does Oracle MERGE Handles Table Join Automatically?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to ORACLE MERGE Command.

I intend to insert a row into a target table based on a source table data.
The source table has Foreign Key Relation to Target Table. Column1 and Column2 in source table must exist to allow a row with those values in Target Table.

My Merge query looks like this.

```
MERGE into TARGET_TABLE target 
USING (
      Select column1, column2 from SOURCE_TABLE where column3='somevalue'
) source
ON (
    source.column1 is null or target.column4='anotherValue'
)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (
    target.column1,
    target.column2,
    target.column3,
    target.column4
) VALUES (
    source.column1,
    source.column2,
    'somevalue3',
    'anotherValue'
)
```

It inserts one row and only when it finds that source.column1 is existing for the source.column3 value of 'somevalue' ie not null and,

there is no row in target table whose column1, column2 and column 4 have following values respectively

1. Same value of column1 in source table when column3 is 'someValue'
2. Same value of column2 in source table when column3 is 'someValue'
3. 'anotherValue'

I need an explanation as to why it matches Point1 and Point2 above even though my MATCH conditions in 'ON' clause does not include them.

When I coded this I expected multiple rows to NOT MATCH the condition since there are many rows in target table where column4 does not has value anotherValue.

**ATTEMPT TO ELABORATE # 1**

**TABLE 1 (SOURCE)**

COL1    COL2    COL3

a1        a2     a3

**TABLE 2 (TARGET)**

COL1     COL2     COL3    COL4

No row

*DESIRED Behavior:*

Insert a row in TABLE 2

1. if source table has a row where COL3 = 'a3' and
2. if there is no row in target with col1 = a1 and col2 = a2 and col4 = b4
3. Data to be inserted in Target table is: col1 = a1, col2 = a2 and col4 = b4

**OBSERVED BEHAVIOR**

Matches the desired behavior above which surprised me. I wondered that I need to have an ON CLAUSE Like this

```
ON (
    source.column1 is null or source.column1 != target.column1 or source.column2 != target.column2 or target.column4 = 'anotherValue'
)
```

Based on DEMorgan's law:

NOT (A and B) = NOT A or NOT B;

NOT (A OR B ) = NOT A and NOT B

Comment: I just Tried to understand the problem ... and failed miserably. May be you could provide a specific example of desired and actual behaviour.

Comment: Normally the `ON` clause should be a join between `source` and `target`. Since there is no join, my guess is it is generating a Cartesian product and the only row not matched is the one where `source.column1` is not null and `target.column4` is not  `'anotherValue'`. Some sample data would help clarify your issue.

Comment: I Apologize for complexity. I am myself finding the problem difficult to comprehend and explain. Though I have added some elaboration.